# Google Play Report Unsupported API but it is in AppCompat

Tags: android, google-play, android-appcompat

I uploaded a new app bundle to Google Play for testing and I checked the pre-launch report this morning which is complaining that I'm using greylisted private APIs which I'm not supposed to use... but the APIs are being used by the v7 AppCompat library, not me.

So, what the heck am I supposed to do about this?

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(ViewUtils.java:84)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:685)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.inadaydevelopment.wordventure.NavControllerActivity_.setContentView(NavControllerActivity_.java:55)
    at com.inadaydevelopment.wordventure.NavControllerActivity.onCreate(NavControllerActivity.java:59)
    at com.inadaydevelopment.wordventure.NavControllerActivity_.onCreate(NavControllerActivity_.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I'm using Android Annotations, so my code isn't calling setContentView() directly, but this is what the generated code is doing... it's just setting the content view with a resource layout id:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    onViewChangedNotifier_.notifyViewChanged(this);
}
```

Comment: What version of AppCompat are you using? Do you see the same when you're using AndroidX AppCompat `1.1.0-beta01` (the latest)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake My build.gradle has `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue in AppCompat](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123699881#comment12):

> What is left right now:
>
> - ViewUtils - View.computeFitSystemWindows and **View.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows**
> - AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper - TextView.getLayoutAlignment
> - SearchView - AutoCompleteTextView.ensureImeVisible
> - DropDownListView - AbsListView.mIsChildViewEnabled (field)

Note that as per the [28.0.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#28-0-0), there's not going to be anymore Support Library releases so you'll need to [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to get any bug fixes such as this one.

Comment: Does this mean I should be able to ignore it?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this, that's correct. Note that as per the [28.0.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#28-0-0), there's not going to be anymore Support Library releases so you'll need to [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to get any bug fixes such as this one.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't familiar with AndroidX. Can you add your comment into the main answer? Then I'll accept that as the answer.

Comment: AndroidX still does this too. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/widget/ViewUtils.java

Comment: Still not resolved, but the source moved: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/widget/ViewUtils.java